# SSH "kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer"

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, raspbian, openssh, fail2ban

**The setup:**

- Raspberry 3B running Raspbian Stretch 9 on an external HDD and using ZRAM
- Raspi used as a webserver running LAMP and MERN stacks and accessed remotely via SSH with 1 IDE (Coda for Mac OS)
- SSH port forwarded by router with static IP
- fail2ban running

**The problem:**

When accessing the raspberry from a remote location (over the Internet) via SSH, it works until the connection hangs. This occurs randomly. 
I can sometimes SSH it again after few minutes, and sometimes not until I restart the Raspi.

**What I've tried:**

- SSH in verbose mode from remote location:

```
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.1
kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

- SSH in verbose mode from local network (I actually SSH another machine on the local network remotely, then SSH the Raspi from that machine). *Same result*: `Connection reset by peer`
- Checked `/etc/hosts.allow` and `/etc/hosts.deny` *=> Nothing there*
- Checked iptables via `iptables -L --line-number` *=> Nothing there*
- Checked logs: `/var/log/fail2ban.log` and `sudo journalctl -t sshd` *=> Nothing striking there*
- Updated `sshd_config` with `no DNS`
- Re-installed SSH via `apt-get --reinstall install openssh-server openssh-client`

I am running out of ideas here and no clue about what's happening.
As someone encountered the same problem with SSH connection before ?
Could it be a load issue on the raspberry ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Long story short, my problem had nothing to do with a network issue and was fixed by examining the ***syslog***.

In details:

I noticed that none of the webapps (via LAMP or MERN stacks) while up and running before the issue started, were not reachable anymore.

So I dug up the syslog with the `tail -f -n X /var/log/syslog` command (replacing X with the number of lines you want to display).
I then noticed few lines mentioning a **Voltage problem** (sorry I did keep the exact terms). But basically it meant that my Raspi which an external HDD was plugged on did not have a strong enough power supply.

Then it looked that the HDD was unmounted and the system crashed, which explains all the issues mentioned above.

So I removed the HDD put the SD card back and ran the Raspi again while going through the ***syslog*** again and monitoring the memory with ***htop***. It turned out that when I started both the apache and node servers, the RAM and SWAP memories were getting full repeating the same consequences mentioned above.

So finally I increased the SWAP memory by using ZRAM. [Link here](https://hackaday.io/project/29898-boost-your-raspberry-pi-in-minutes/details) .

Now everything runs well but still monitoring.